# CSS: my body tag is not working

Tags: html, css

For some crazy reason my body tag is not working at all.  It is the only CSS that isn't working.  I am trying to have a background behind the content of my website and have the content be about 80% of the body.  So that I can have two bars on either side of my website which kind of acts as a border.  Kind of how there seems to be two white bars on either side of stack overflow.

```
 <style type="text/css">

body{
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}

#content {
    font: 14px/1.4 'Times New Roman', sans-serif;
    width: 80%;
    max-width:1260px;
    min-width: 780px;
    background-color: #89837A;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<!--Replace link with good web font you want.<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> - See more at: http://www.newthinktank.com/2011/09/how-to-layout-a-website/#sthash.lWAaNgcS.dpuf -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CPLS_Stylesheet.css">

<!--<div class='error' style='display:none'>Event Created</div>-->

<title>MyWebsite</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="content">

        HEADER

        <div id="contentBackground">
            CONTENT
        </div><!--End of contentBackground-->
    </div> <!--End of content-->

</body>
</html>
```

No matter what color I change the body tag to the background always stays white.  The content is the correct color.

Comment: Don't use any XHTML-related `doctype`; just use the HTML5 `<!doctype html>`.

Comment: It totally works: http://jsfiddle.net/GxpEF/

Comment: I think forcing your `min-width` for the `div` is causing you a problem.

Comment: Is your window wide enough to see your "border"? Why don't you put the border as padding on the `body` tag?

Comment: I think it's missing the height of the div

Comment: What I posted was a very very very small part of my website.  When I tested it, it didn't work but apparently it does work.  However, my actual website still does not work.  Upon further testing it seems like for some reason if I replace the CSS link: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CPLS_Stylesheet.css"> with the actual CSS then it works, but with the link the the external style sheet the body breaks, and only the body breaks...any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 4):

Don't put style link at the top of the some other link. that's why body design is not working. Put style link under the all the link

Comment: Yes, I have added my CSS style on top of another link, your answer helped me.

Comment: yep. that was it for me

Answer (score 3):

Is this: `<style type="text/css">` in your CSS or is that just a mistake?

Unless that's an accident when your wrote that code, that's not valid CSS. The only time that's allowed is using the style tags *within* a HTML document to wrap CSS code.

**Okay:**

*index.html*

```
<style>
body {
    background-color: white;
}
</style>
```

**Not okay:**

*style.css*

```
<style>
body {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Since there's no closing tag, it looks like you accidentally copied that from a tutorial using the `<style>` tag inside a HTML document.

Comment: What I posted was a copy of a small part of my website thats why there are errors. When I tested it, it didn't work but apparently it does work according to JWhy. However, my actual website still does not work. Upon further testing it seems like for some reason if I replace the CSS link in my HTML:
 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CPLS_Stylesheet.css">

with the actual CSS then it works(the body background turns black), but when I add the link to the external style sheet the body breaks(the body background turns white), and only the body breaks...any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using some kind of CSS framework make sure you place your custom CSS files, at last, the same thing happened with me I adjusted the order of the files that I
 was including and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact reason why this problem is occurring.
The same problem has been occurred to me. However, I tackled it by using !important after the property in body in CSS file.
e.g. `body{ background:black !important;}`
If you found the actual reason do share it with me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked long ago but here is one solution. Put your css file link as the last one in the  part of your html.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked long ago, but I have just had the exact same issue.
Add a fake element style in your stylesheet before the body.

e.g.

```
#myFakeElement { color:red ; }

body{
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: What does adding a fake element do to solve OP's issue?

Comment: This worked for me too, I can't imagine why. My css and html are very simple and it's not the first time I've done this but my body background-color and width wouldn't show up and this worked. Tried everything else. I wonder if @Mark knows what was wrong and why the fake element would fix something like this.

Comment: Figured it out, there was a wrongly commented comment in front of the body definition in my css. The fake element only worked by shielding the rest of my css from the bad code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  from the style sheet....

I just copied the code to my editor and it worked:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Define both html and body in your style.css, and set their width and height to 100%.

Comment: Adding any element before the body element in the css file will probably work, but not because there is anything wrong with the body tag. The `<style type="text/css">` text should not be in a css file. I'm also sure the change to 100% width and height are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted a long time ago. But—since people are apparently still finding this question, and occasionally still trying to answer it—this is what appears to be going on here:

The code, as it is intended, works as expected. That's probably why many people report testing the code and finding that it works. The most apparent issue is that the code block for the css file starts with `<style type="text/css">` although that line is only necessary when doing css in the html file. If that line is present at the beginning of the css file then the first element referenced (body in this case) is ignored.